# How to represent values as an alias in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to represent results from an SQL query as a different value depending on the result itself? For instance, every time the actual value in the database is 'foo', I would like the results in the table to display it as 'bar' instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a  `case`

```
select case when col1 = 'foo' 
            then 'bar'
            else col1 
       end as col1
from your_table
```